# Tslint not working in Emacs using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, emacs, tslint, flycheck

I'm trying to set up Emacs with Typescript and Angular, using `tide` and `ng2-mode`. I'm having issues with enabling `tslint` in `flycheck`. My source directory is as follows:

app-dir - here is the tslint.json file

app-dir/src/main.ts - here, tslint is working normally

app-dir/src/app/app.component.ts - here tslint is not working at all, flycheck doesn't see any checker :/

Can you help me, how can I debug this?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting this on your init file:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tide
  (flycheck-add-mode 'typescript-tslint 'ng2-ts-mode)
  (flycheck-add-mode 'typescript-tide 'ng2-ts-mode)
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. PLEASE Stackoverflow STOP DOWNVOTING ANSWERS